# Is it possible to change the jQuery default from display:block to display: inline-block when toggleing?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to simply toggle a `<div>`. I set the item being toggled to display: inline; in my CSS so it does not show, and when the item is toggled I see in my Chrome's Inspector the item gets set to display: block;

Is it possible to have this set to display: inline-block instead? If this isn't clear enough I'll provide you with my code...I just don't happen to have it with my right now.

Comment: You can use a class switcher instead to switch between two classes, one3 with display inline and the other with inline-block.

Comment: yes, toggleClass is a better choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can*. but it's not a particularly good idea. It involves tapping in to jQuery's internal _data method, and overriding the browser's determined default display property.

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".toggler").click(function() {
        var dom = $(".showhide");
        jQuery._data(dom[0],"olddisplay","inline-block");
        dom.toggle();
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bstakes/2ncW5/

**I would recommend using some type of class switching, as mentioned in the comments.**